# Python assignment mechanics in multithreaded programs? Functions & Classes

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, variable-assignment

I would like to understand a little bit better the mechanics of assignments in multithreaded programs.

In the following snippet of code, what stops each thread from assigning a new value to `item` before any thread has managed to put send the value to `q_out`?

```
import Queue, threading

q_in = Queue.Queue()
q_out = Queue.Queue()

def worker():
    while True:
        item = q_in.get()
        q_out.put(do_work(item))
        q_in.task_done()
```

I would have thought I would need to do something like the following, which starts a class instance for each thread with its own set of values, but I gather this isn't really necessary?

```
import Queue, threading

q_in = Queue.Queue()
q_out = Queue.Queue()

class Worker(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.item = None

    def run(self):
        self.item = q_in.get()
        q_out.put(do_work(self.item))
        q_in.task_done()
```

So I assume there is either a python mechanic I don't understand or there is some kind of built in functionality to the `threading` or `Queue` modules?

Comment: You do need a thread for each worker. Your first example doesn't make sense. In python, you can execute a function in a different thread, so you don't need the class.

Comment: I think you need to investigate global vs. local variables in Python a little more. Here is a good starting point: http://www.python-course.eu/global_vs_local_variables.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first code example, if you have multiple threads and they each call `worker()` then each thread has a stack on which `item` is created and each `item` refers to a different element of `q_in`.

Also, just to be clear, the function `do_work()` cannot modify what `item` refers to.

In your second snippet, you have essentially move `item` out of the stack and onto the heap where it is associated with an instance of `Worker`.

In both cases each thread has its own `item` which refers to different instances simultaneously.

Also, for novice programmers, you should consider passing `q_in` and `q_out` into the function `worker()` or each instance of a `Worker` rather than having them as global variables.